# How to access aws resources created in other account

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam, aws-access-policy, assume-role

In my use case, I want to access `DynamoDB` table created in AWS account A and Lambda created in account B. For this I have followed many references on Internet which suggests me to use AWS assume role feature.
I have added following permission in Lambda execution role

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-A-number:role/test-db-access"
   }
}
```

Following is the trust relationship of Lambda

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
           "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
       },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-A-number:root"
       },
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In account A, I have created role(test-db-access) for allowing others to access this account and added `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess`  and AdministratorAccess policies. Following is the trust relationship I have added in this account

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
     {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::aws-account-B-number:role/sam-dev-test- 
            TestLambda-LambdaRole-1FH5IC18J0MYT"
         },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
     },
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
           "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
         },
       "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
     }
  ]
}
```

Following is the Java code I have added to access Dynamo DB instance

```
AssumeRoleRequest assumeRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest()
            .withRoleArn("arn:aws:iam::aws-account-A-number:role/test-db-access").withRoleSessionName("cross_acct_lambda").withDurationSeconds(900);
final AWSSecurityTokenService sts = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("eu-west-1").build();
final Credentials credentials = sts.assumeRole(assumeRequest).getCredentials();
```

following is the crash log coming on executing lambda

`{
  "errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::aws-account-B-number:assumed-role/sam-dev-test-TestLambda-LambdaRole-1FH5IC18J0MYT/sam-dev-test-TestLambda-LambdaFunction-73TVOBN6VXXX is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::aws-account-A-number:role/test-db-access (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 100bd3a3-3f9c-11ea-b642-d3b4d9ff35de)",
  "errorType": "com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException"
}`

Comment: Could you please clarify: Which account has the IAM User credentials you are using the account the service? Also, could you clarify what you wish to do with Lambda in Account B? Do you just wish to invoke a Lambda function?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I wish to invoke lambda in account B . This lambda is trying to access Dynamo DB table present in account A.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Could you please clarify: Which account has the IAM User credentials you are using the account the service?
I'm not able to understand this question. I have created a role in Account A which has adminAccess policy . I'm trying to assume this role in my lambda code, but it is throwing unauth exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears your requirements are:

- From an AWS Lambda function in `Account-B`, access a DynamoDB table in `Account-A`

To reproduce your situation I did the following:

- Created a DynamoDB table in `Account-A`
- Created an IAM Role (`Role-A`) in `Account-A` with the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "dynamodb:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:ap-southeast-2:<Account-A>:table/Inventory"
        }
    ]
}
```

And this Trust Relationship (pointing to the Role created in the next step):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-B>:role/role-b"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Created an IAM Role (`Role-B`) in `Account-B` for use with the Lambda function, with this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A>:role/role-a"
        }
    ]
}
```

And with this Trust Relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

- Created an AWS Lambda function in `Account-B` that will:

  - Assume `Role-A` in `Account-A`
  - Access the DynamoDB table in `Account-A`

I'm a Python person, so my function is:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Assume Role
    sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

    response = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::<Account-A>:role/stack-role-a', 
        RoleSessionName='bar')

    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    )

    # Update DynamoDB
    dynamodb_client = session.client('dynamodb')

    dynamodb_client.update_item(
        TableName='Inventory',
        Key={'Item': {'S': 'foo'}},
        UpdateExpression="ADD #count :increment",
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            '#count': 'count'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues = {
            ':increment': {'N': '1'},
        }
    )
```

I tested this by clicking **Test** on the Lambda function in `Account-B`. It **successfully updated** the DynamoDB table in `Account-A`.

I suspect the difference is with your trust policies, which appear to be a little bit different.