# update Route53 record set - cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-route53

Am facing an access issue when trying to update record set using lambda function.

- Lambda - Account A
- Route53 - Account B

I have an IAM role attached to lambda in Account A with an assume role permission to an IAM role in Account B. The IAM role in account B has access to update the record set in Account B.

When am triggering lambda, am receiving user is not authorized to access this resource.

Can someone help me, if i'm missing anything here or do I need any additional setup.

Comment: How are you making the call to S3?

Comment: Let's focus on the "not authorized" message. Is this happening _after_ the call to `AssumeRole()`? If so, can you show your code that is using the credentials returned by `AssumeRole()`? Here's a question with similar cross-account Lambda usage, which might help: [How to access aws resources created in other account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941610/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Am sure that it passed the assume role. because i've added the required assume role permissions on both the IAM Roles. Below is the error: [user: aws:sts::account-id:assumed-role/role-name/lambda-function-name] is not authorized to access this resource. Am receiving this error when trying to update the record set in Account B using lambda function from account A.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth am not making any calls to s3 here.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Route53.

Comment: I think what John is asking is along the same lines of what I'm trying to figure out. When you make the call to Route53 in the other account you have to make a call to assume the role in that account. The Lambda runs under the role in Account A. Then you need to assume the role in Account B (using STS). From there you can make the call to Route53 in Account B, using the credentials supplied to you by STS.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth i've lambda function in Account-A and am using boto3 to UPSERT the record set in Account-B HostedZone (am directly specifying the hostedzoneid as per below documentation). [https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53.html#Route53.Client.change_resource_record_sets]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use STS to get a token to call Route53 on Account B. Here are the docs on STS in boto3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role

You'll get back a credential that you will use to make the call to Route53.

Comment: i did tried adding the sts assume role as below, still receiving the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Lambda function in `Account-A` to call Route 53 in `Account-B`.

This will require:

- An IAM Role (`Role-A`) in `Account-A` that is assigned to the Lambda function. It should grant permission to call `AssumeRole()`, with the `Resource` set to the ARN of `Role-B` in `Account-B`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-B>:role/role-b"
        }
    ]
}
```

And with this Trust Relationship:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

- An IAM Role (`Role-B`) in `Account-B` that has permission to call Route 53. It should also have a **trust policy** allowing it to be assumed by `Role-A` in `Account-A`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "route53:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

(This is an overly powerful policy. It would be better to limit it to the specific Route 53 actions that are required.)

And this Trust Relationship (pointing to the Role created in the previous step):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<Account-A>:role/role-a"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Really appreciate your response. The permissions part looks good as mentioned in my earlier comments.

Comment: Would this works with AWS CLI? I have added "role a" with an ec2 box with trust relation ship "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com". I am not using lambda, trying to create from another ec2 box in Account A. and trying to create record in Account B. All other things done as mentioned you. But getting authorization access issue.

Comment: @AshishMishra Please create a new question with complete details, rather than asking via a comment on an old question.